# ListView footer not showing until after starting the activity for the second time

Tags: android, listview

I'm writing an Android app to keep up with shopping lists. The main view has a list of all existing lists and tapping an item will open the details view that has a button for adding items to the list. The items are on a list and the add button is on the `ListView` footer.

When I create a new list the add item button is not showing but when I return to the details view the button is there. I added the screenshots at the end to clarify the problem. I've tested this with an actual device as well.

The layout XML has `RelativeLayout` with two child `LinearLayouts`, one for the static header and one for the `ListView`. Could this cause issues? The code is working but how can it work only after the initial save?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lrqjD.png

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First of all, don't wrap ListView ( or any SIGNLE view for that matter ) in the LinearLayouts without having a good reason to do that. Nothing gonna break, it just looks bad .. 
From what i see - you can build THAT UI by placing all views inside single RelativeLayouts.

For the add button, i wouldn't make it as footer - i'd just would add this at the bottom

ListTitleLabel
ListTitle ( below label)
SaveButton (below title )
AddButton  ( align parent bottom)
ListView ( above the Add, below Save )

Something like that..

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I did as you suggested and I suppose it works just as well with the static footer.

Answer (score 0):

In your `Activity` you need to call something like

```
getListView().addFooterView(layoutInflater.inflate(R.id.itemlistfooter)
```

obviously you'll need to grab a `LayoutInflater` first...

Comment: In the original code I did inflate the external view and it worked like I described.